# AES Encryption - Generating a random key in PHP

Tags: php, encryption, random, aes

So I am trying to do the following:

1) `$session_key` => randomly generated AES key

2) encrypt `$data` => using AES encryption using `$session_key` and `$data`

3) I skipped some steps in between this to actually make it a secure form of encryption, but obviously, use `$session_key` to decrypt the data

I am having trouble figuring out how to randomly generate a secure key to to encrypt the data with.

Can anyone help?

Comment: Does your question actually boil down to "how to generate a random, like, *really random* string"?

Comment: I guess. I really wanted to generate a random 256-bit AES key which I guess I need some sort of random value to encrypt it? @deceze

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[openssl_random_pseudo_bytes()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.openssl-random-pseudo-bytes.php) is really secure and easy to use.